# Is there a phrase that is the opposite of "putting two and two together"?

Tags: idioms

I've been looking for a phrase that would describe the opposite of putting two and two together.

For example:

"I thought Cindy's murder had everything to do with Mark's disappearance, but as it turns out, instead of putting two and two together and getting four, I put two and two together to get five, not realizing it was actually her estranged son that had done the deed!"

Or as someone else put it, I'm looking for a better way to say "I came to the wrong conclusion"

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood the meaning of the phrase.  "Putting two and two together" isn't about correlation, it's about methodical deduction.  As in "I can put two and two together and get 4" - in other words, "I can follow a simple chain of clues/thoughts and come to the right conclusion".  Alternatively, "We watched as he put two and two together and got 5" means "We watched him stupidly misunderstand the situation".  So I think your question is invalid.

Comment: Well I don't want to use that whole phrase in a sentence. For example, I don't want to write "What I wanted to do was this, and logically, I thought I was putting two and two together and getting four, but what I was actually doing was putting two and two together and getting five". See how wordy that is?

Comment: Couldn't you just say you made an invalid deduction or came to the wrong conclusion?

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark It is now not clear whether you want the opposite of some more appropriate phrase, or whether you really do want the opposite of "putting two and two together" but worded it badly.

Comment: I want the opposite of "putting two and two together and got four" but don't want to repeat it as "putting two and two together and got five"

Comment: You could just make up something appropriate, like "I thought I was  digging for a deep and insightful deduction, but what I ended up with was adding 2 and blue and getting floor."

Comment: @Hellion that sounds like it's going to confuse the reader even more, despite the fact I understand what you're saying, I'm not sure if others would understand the same thing

Comment: correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: @JosephNeathawk So "I recently explored the idea of X being tied to Y, but I guess correlation does not imply causation" sounds good?

Comment: "Putting two and two together" means to combine pieces of evidence to reach a conclusion (ostensibly logically).  The opposite would either be to "jump to a conclusion" or to "dither" and not make a decision, depending on which part of the idiom you want to invert.

Comment: Irrelevant aside: the t-shirt I'm wearing today says, "2+2=5... for sufficiently large values of 2."

Comment: Or _.. for appropriate definitions of "+" and "="_

Comment: More to the point: I still don't know what you're asking. "Putting two and two together" doesn't mean *anything* like what you assert ("I correlated A and B together and they both have strong correlation"). You need to edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: If you don't know what the original phrase means, the opposite of it will be even more problematical.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark Your answer doesn't help.  Your question is, one way or the other, poorly phrased and unclear.  You've done nothing to clean it up or clarify.  Martha's comment backs me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Debunk*, as in *I **debunked** the idea of a correlation between A and B.*

Defined by Google as:

> expose the falseness or hollowness of (a myth, idea, or belief)

Comment: So I can say "I thought the cause for X was Y, but I debunked that correlation" So, I exposed myself, in a way?

Comment: Yes, all part of good science.  But you could alternately use *disprove* which has more neutral connotations, or even *ruled out* which is even milder.

Comment: Debunked is not good.  To debunk is to expose and defeat the (unscientific or hypocritical) arguments and claims of others, not to disprove your own hypothesis.

Comment: "Falsify" would be more correct than "debunk".  Still unsure of the actual meaning of the question, of course, but given your interpretation, "Falsify", as in "To prove a statement or theory to be false".

Answer (score 2):

How about: "I divided by zero and got nothin'"

Answer (score 1):

You could say *It turned out A and B were [orthogonal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/orthogonal)*.

> (Of variates) statistically independent.